# PHP Netbeans, Cannot Connect to server via SFTP

Tags: php, netbeans

Im trying to connect my project via sFTP. and everytime I run the project it says.

```
Cannot Connect to Server http://abcd.efg.com
Reason: java.net.UnkownHostException: http://abcd.efg.com
```

But when I hit ok. the application then starts at my browser. which is weird, I set up the project as New Project, and PHP Application with existing Sources because I already have a project. then set "Run as: remote website (ftp,Sftp)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use abcd.efg.com instead of http://abcd.efg.com
```

you cannot connect over sftp and http at the same time :).
Netbeans is expecting the hostname to connect over sftp, surely it doesnt like http://hostname.com over :22

Comment: haha. i see what you did there, but its still the same. i get rid of "http://" and as I test the connection. it succeeded. but when I run the project itself. it gives the error again.

Comment: what is the url that you gave while importing project from remote server? by default it runs http://domainName/index.php
however dont worry about running the project from netbeans unless you are using Xdebud or any other debugger. just make the changes in netbeans and open up the url in ur browser.

Comment: i use domainName/Bootstrap.php, and yep. I use XAMPP. so with this XAMPP I dont have to worry for this unknowhostexception thing that goes with netbeans? also I dont know if I setup XAMPP correctly. guess I have to make sure about this though. Thanks for the info.

Comment: also. when I try to delete all the codes from a certain page. for example index.php, and try to run it. Nothing happened. the page is still intact. like nothin has been deleted after all

Comment: domainName/Bootstrap.php -> thi doesnt sound right. because you never execute/run your bootstrap file.

Comment: which framwork are you using? does it have a public/index.php?

Comment: So that's what ive doin wrong after all. cause Im a bit confused which is which. I have a folder here which is "Application", and the other one is "Interface", this project has zend framework. so its a bit confusing which index.phtml should I use.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12894/discussion-between-eswar-rajesh-pinapala-and-newbie)

Comment: You might want to consider reading about MVC and Zend framework before setting u the project and start building.
this might be a good place to start
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html
it wont take much time but will hellp you understand what are models/views/controllers
and how Zend places these in a folder heirarchy(like any MVC) and helps you design an application with much cleaner code